# error C2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'X' to 'X'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a C++/Win32/MFC project in Visual Studio 2008, and I'm getting a strange error message when I compile it.

I've created a small project to demonstrate the problem, and the main code is

```
#ifndef _MyObject_h
#define _MyObject_h

class MyObject
{
public:
        MyObject()
        {
        }
};

#endif // _MyObject_h
// --- END MyObject.h



// --- BEGIN ObjectData.h
#ifndef _ObjectData_h
#define _ObjectData_h

template <typename DataPolicy>
class ObjectData
{
public:
        DataPolicy *data;

        ObjectData() :
                data(NULL)
        {
        }

        ObjectData(const ObjectData<DataPolicy> &copy) :
                data(copy.data)
        {
        }

        ObjectData<DataPolicy> & operator=(const ObjectData<DataPolicy> &copy)
        {
                this->data = copy.data;
                return *this;
        }
};

#endif // _ObjectData_h
// --- END ObjectData.h



// --- BEGIN Tool.h
#ifndef _Tool_h
#define _Tool_h

#include "ObjectData.h"

template <typename ObjectPolicy>
class Tool
{
private:
        ObjectData<typename ObjectPolicy> _object;

public:
        Tool(ObjectData<typename ObjectPolicy> obj);
};

#endif // _Tool_h
// --- END Tool.h



// --- BEGIN Tool.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Tool.h"

template <typename ObjectPolicy>
Tool<ObjectPolicy>::Tool(ObjectData<typename ObjectPolicy> obj) :
        _object(obj)
{
}
// --- END Tool.cpp



// --- BEGIN Engine.h
#ifndef _Engine_h
#define _Engine_h

#include "Tool.h"
#include "MyObject.h"

class Engine
{
private:
        MyObject *_obj;

public:
        Engine();
        ~Engine();
        void DoSomething();
};

#endif // _Engine_h
// --- END Engine.h



// --- BEGIN Engine.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Engine.h"

Engine::Engine()
{
        this->_obj = new MyObject();
}

Engine::~Engine()
{
        delete this->_obj;
}

void Engine::DoSomething()
{
        ObjectData<MyObject> objData;
        objData.data = this->_obj;
        // NEXT LINE IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
        Tool< ObjectData<MyObject> > *tool = new Tool< ObjectData<MyObject> >(objData);
}
// --- END Engine.cpp
```

Errors:

> Engine.cpp
>   c:\projects\myproject\myproject\engine.cpp(18) : error C2664: 
> 'Tool::Tool(ObjectData)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'ObjectData' to 'ObjectData'
>          with
>          [
>              ObjectPolicy=ObjectData,
>              DataPolicy=ObjectData
>          ]
>          and
>          [
>              DataPolicy=MyObject
>          ]
>          and
>          [
>              DataPolicy=ObjectData
>          ]
>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
>   1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
>   MyProject - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Line 18, where is it in the presented code?

Comment: Is this your real code? `ObjectData<typename ObjectPolicy> _object;` won't ever compile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. First of all, you are using the `typename` keyword in a wrong way. `typename` can be used only when *qualified* type names are used (and is required when the type names are *dependent*), which is not your case:

```
template <typename ObjectPolicy>
class Tool
{
private:
    ObjectData<typename ObjectPolicy> _object; // "typename" is not needed!
public:
    Tool(ObjectData<typename ObjectPolicy> obj); // "typename" is not needed!
};
```

The problem you complain about, however, is in your instantiation of the `Tool` class template:

```
Tool< ObjectData<MyObject> > *tool = new Tool< ObjectData<MyObject> >(objData);
```

Your `Tool<>` template contains a member variable of type `ObjectData<ObjectPolicy>`, where `ObjectPolicy` is the class template parameter. However, in the line above you instantiate `Tool` with `ObjectData<MyObject>` as a parameter. This means your member variable will have type `ObjectData<ObjectData<MyObject>>`, and this will also be the type of the constructor's parameter.

Because of this, you are trying to invoke a constructor which accepts an `ObjectData<ObjectData<MyObject>>` with an argument of a mismatching type `ObjectData<MyObject>`. Hence, the error you get.

You should change your instantiation into:

```
Tool< MyObject > *tool = new Tool< MyObject >(objData);
```

Another problem is that you have the definition of `Tool`'s member functions in a separate `.cpp` files. You should not do that: the linker won't be able to see it when processing a separate translation unit.

To solve this problem, put the definitions of your class template's member functions into the same header where the class template is defined (`Tool.h` in your case).

Comment: Ok, I've done it and now Linker is complaining the following:  `1>Engine.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Tool<class MyObject>::Tool<class MyObject>(class ObjectData<class MyObject>)" (??0?$Tool@VMyObject@@@@QAE@V?$ObjectData@VMyObject@@@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Engine::DoSomething(void)" (?DoSomething@Engine@@QAEXXZ)`

Comment: @Alexandre: see the last paragraph in the edited answer. You can't have the constructor's definition in a separate `.cpp` file. Put it in `Tool.h` and the error should vanish

Comment: `typename` is also allowed in front of a qualified non-dependent type name, for those times when you don't want to work out whether or not something is technically dependent.  But yeah, it's not allowed in front of unqualified names (no `Class::`) as seen here.

Comment: @aschepler: That's what I meant, but yes, I was not very precise. Thank you

Comment: Thank you all, guys, I've made all the corrections in the real code and it compiled (and linked) ok. Now it's runtime debugging... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Tool< ObjectData<MyObject> > *tool = new Tool< ObjectData<MyObject> >(objData);

template <typename ObjectPolicy>
Tool<ObjectPolicy>::Tool(ObjectData<typename ObjectPolicy> obj) :
        _object(obj)
{
}
```

It seems to me you might not really understand how templates work.
Check out the following [C++ Templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/)
What you currently have is invalid C++ syntax. Take a look and give it another shot.

Comment: I've removed "typename" keyword from inside class and constructor declarations and the result was the same...